# Идентификация пользователя на сервере

Tags: php, база-данных, api, сервер

Есть сервер на php, на нем бд. С сервером должны работать сайт и мобильное приложение. При авторизации на клиенты приходят айди пользователя. При совершении пользователем каких-то действий, которые вносят изменения в бд, на сервер, вместе с содержимым запроса, также отправляется этот самый айди пользователя, и там в содействии с ним какие-то операции совершаются(На пример пользователь хочет поменять себе возраст). В чем суть вопроса - как мне идентифицировать, что некто, совершающий какое-то действие является тем самым пользователем от имени которого совершается действие?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто как мысль:

1. id пользователя шифровать, например с помощью `md5()` добавляя какое-то значение (например, в момент создания добавлять `time()`)
2. хранить в БД вместе с данными пользователя зашифрованное значение
3. отправлять пользователю тоже зашифрованное значение
4. при действиях пользователя - искать его не по id, а по этому хэшу, если в БД есть - все норм

Или вы имеете ввиду физически идентифицировать пользователя, что именно Вася Пупкин сидит за компом и правит данные, а не его друг с аккаунта Васи?